# Merging of two csv files using awk based on common column

Tags: csv, unix, join, awk

I have one file with 11 columns with first column as primary id - P1
second csv with three columns with first column as same primary id - P1, though not at same level in both files,
I am merging both files using below command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$2] = $3; next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,h[$2]}' first.csv second.csv > final.csv
```

however, getting only three columns in new csv

Answer (score 1):

You should see if `join` wouldn't be an easier solution. Type `man join` for that:

```
join - join lines of two files on a common field
```

Comment: i have used join -t, <(sort -t, -k1 second.csv) <(sort -t, -k1 first.csv) > third.csv, however it is giving illegal byte sequence error

Answer (score 0):

If first.csv has 11 columns and second.csv has three, then you have your files are in the wrong order. Try like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$2] = $3; next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,h[$2]}' second.csv first.csv > final.csv
```

You are also not using the first column as keys in this example, but the second one.